# Orbeon - how to get or set checkboxes

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have a simple questio: how to get/set checkbox from checkboxes in orbeon?

Something like this:
/myCheckboxes[value="itemVal"].isChecked()

Comment: Is this for a form you created in Form Builder, or for XForms you're writting by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, the values are space-separated. To extract them, instead of `contains()` use this to check if value `42` is included:

```
tokenize(../myCheckboxGroup, '\s+') = '42'
```

This splits the value on spaces with the `\s+` regexp and returns a string sequence.

By the way you don't need to write:

```
if (condition) true() else false()
```

You can always just write:

```
condition
```

Answer (score 0):

i've made something like this:

to set: simply set value of checkbox group as a string compound by all items values i want to have checked separated by a space.

To check if checkbox is checked i`ve made something like this:

if(contains(../myCheckboxGroup, '2')) then true() else false()

but its not good solution for example because it's making that max items is 10 if i want to add values as a successive integers.